# srss data query parameter / variable

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

how can i pass a value from one dataset value as a variable/parameter into another dataset query to populate a table cell?

eg. Table displaying DataSet1 results. Last column comes from DataSet2 which has following query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE = $1
```

The WHERE value I want to come from a field value from DataSet1 resultset. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up an internal parameter with your other dataset using "Default Values" "Get values from a query", then reference this parameter in your other dataset.  Note your SQL Syntax needs correction in the WHERE clause.  Note you may see an error if the dataset to be populated executes before the populating dataset.

If your second table is in a subreport, you can pass the field from your first query by simply referencing it as a parameter in the subreport:

```
=Fields!DataValue.Value
```